# Is there any way how to programally change background color of "documentation" in Eclipse IDE based on the color theme?

Tags: eclipse, documentation, darkmode

I'm seeking a way to dynamically adjust the colors of the documentation section in Eclipse IDE based on the color theme selected by the user. Currently, when I switch Eclipse to a dark theme, the HTML pages in the documentation still have a white background, which is not consistent with the dark theme.

I want to achieve this programmatically rather than through the preferences menu. Is there a way to programmatically modify the colors of the documentation section to match the chosen color theme in Eclipse? E.g way how to change css based on the eclipse theme?

Thank you for any insights or guidance!

my current version 2023-06 (4.28.0)
[image]

I explored the Eclipse IDE documentation settings but found no direct option to dynamically adjust the colors of the documentation section based on the IDE's color theme. I also investigated possible solutions within the Eclipse plugin development environment, but haven't yet found a suitable approach.

Ideally, I expected that switching the Eclipse theme to dark mode would automatically adjust the background color of the documentation section to match the theme, ensuring consistency with the overall IDE appearance. However, since this didn't happen, I'm now looking for a programmatic solution to achieve this behavior.

Comment: The way for this feature would to make pull requests to the [help system of the Eclipse platform](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform/tree/master/ua). But keep in mind, that the help content is contributed by different plugins with their own HTML+CSS that might needed to be adapted as well (CSS needs to have `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` section).

Comment: The white background that is shown in your screenshot is hard-coded here (you are welcome to do a pull request to change this): https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator/blob/f4d57a9cb4abf0bc5fd1ad1e0fc54fca69123c91/eclipse.platform.common/bundles/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-42.htm#L12

Comment: Yeah, for this particular page it is hard-coded. But what if I have my own html pages, which I want to show there. I need to somehow inject them CSS for dark mode I guess.

Comment: You are talking about Windows, right? For help content the browser widget is used which has some limitations on Windows (see [old bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548960)). As workaround you can use the [_Help Content Producer_ extension point](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_help_contentProducer.html) to generate a CSS file depending which mode is set.